# import <> vs import "" in iOS project.what is their difference

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I saw some `import <...>` code in our project, which pod is imported by cocoapods, when `<...>` is a system path to search, usually used as `import <UIKit.h>`. Why the third lib from pod still could use `import <...>` rather than `import ""`?.

Answer (score -1):

You should generally not use `#import <foo>` and for pods you can use `@import Pod;`.

I collected the most current way of importing things in a mixed project here: [Current way of importing in a mixed Objective-C / Swift project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49253937/current-way-of-importing-in-a-mixed-objective-c-swift-project)